# Simplification of appender function using std::accumulate

Tags: c++, append, std

I wanted a simple function that takes a collection of strings and appends them and returns one string which is each string item appended together.  I thought std::accumulate was the way to go but interested to hear if this code could be improved.

Is there a simpler append type function that can be used here instead of the lambda?

Is this overly complicated and best achieved by some other code?

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

std::string concatenate(std::vector<std::string> strings)
{
    return std::accumulate(strings.begin(), strings.end(), std::string(""), [](std::string s1, std::string s2) { return s1 + s2; });
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> vec2{ "aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","fff" };
    std::cout << concatenate(vec2) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The lambda is not required in the call of std::accumiulate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can omit the lambda entirely (or use `std::plus<>{}`).

Also the `""` can be removed from `std::string("")`, or the whole third argument can be removed if you switch to `std::reduce`:

```
std::reduce(strings.begin(), strings.end());
```

Also `concatenate` should take the vector by a const reference, or even better a `std::span<const std::string>` (by value).

Also libfmt can be used for this:

```
fmt::format("{}", fmt::join(strings, ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be simplified with [C++17 fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), there is no an intermediate or a temporary collection needed.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename ...S>
std::string concatenate(S&&... strings) {
    using namespace std::string_literals;
    return (""s + ... + strings);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << concatenate("aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","fff") << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: And where is there a vector of strings?

Comment: @Vlad If you need a vector, see another answer.

Comment: It is the author of the question that uses a vector.

Comment: @Vlad OP uses a vector in the example, but the question is a bit different: *a simple function that takes a collection of strings*.